# Consumir una api rest mediante un json web token con token de acceso

Tags: php, laravel, api

Mi problema es el siguiente: quiero obtener los datos de citas en un formato `json`, pero tengo dudas.

Tengo una `url` con el usuario y la clave esta url por postman, me genera un `token` que uso en otra `url` y esta es la que me genera un archivo `json` con los datos necesarios.
Todo esto lo hago por medio de postman: ahora el problema es cómo traigo esos datos a mi proyecto que está basado en php laravel.
He visto que usan funciones como `json_decode( file_get_contents+url)`, pero ¿cómo agregaría el token? ya que solo la `url` sin el token no me daría los datos necesarios.

En `postman` pongo esa `url` y debo agregar en `authentificacion` el método **bearer token + el token** para que me genere el archivo json[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Simple, haz un request primero para obtener el token, luego si el token retorna correctamente haz otro request pero esta vez con el token que te retorno el primer request, este lo guardas en db, cookie, localstorage o donde necesites, luego lo envías en la petición anexándolo al header, Postman te da ejemplos de como hacerlo con codigo presionaldo el simbolo de "</>"

Answer (score 0):

Es fácil, solo recuerda que el token se envía a las cabeceras o HEADERS del servidor, en **php** existen variables globales donde tienes acceso a esta información por ejemplo [$_SERVER](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) tiene el índice **HTTP_AUTHORIZATION** aquí es donde es almacenado.

Por ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
y para acceder a esta información con php:

```
$X = $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'];
var_dump($X);
```

le asigno el valor del token a la variable **$X**
y me regresa:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]